# Exec() not interpreting the multiple commands correctly

Tags: java, ssh, runtime, exec, runtime.exec

I am trying to run two commands through exec() but it seems as if the commands are not correctly parsed.

I have the following code of line:

```
cmd = "scp -rp /mnt/backups/updateimage/images root@"+Arr.get(i)+":/usr/site/html ; ssh Arr.get(i)+" /usr/site/html/images/untar1.sh";

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Any idea how can I format my cmd string so that exec interprets it correctly ?
Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `"`, don't know if you noticed: cmd = "scp -rp /mnt/backups/updateimage/images root@"+Arr.get(i)+":/usr/site/html ; ssh"+ Arr.get(i)+" /usr/site/html/images/untar1.sh";

Comment: MByD that still doesn't work I gave ssh"+Arr.get(i)+" .... but still it didn't work . any ideas as to why it is still not working ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Execution of multiple, semi-colon delimited commands is feature provided by shells, but you are executing the `scp` command.

If you want to use a shell, you should specify *it* as the command to be executed, with the actual commands as its arguments.

Comment: erickson , the scp command has the following format :
**scp [[user@]from-host:]source-file [[user@]to-host:][destination-file]** . So where would I put my commands as arguments . The command is copying the contents from a folder to images folder on a server and then on that server running a script from another folder . I am trying this but still unsuccessful so far. Any suggestions  ??
Thanks !